# Какой Сервер выбрать для Java

Tags: java

Пытаюсь изучать разработку web приложений на Java. Попробовал TomCat, с ним проблем не возникло, вот только это не полноценный сервер, а хотелось бы изучать, что то более серьезное. Взялся за Payara, но с ним уже бьюсь целую неделю и ни как не могу запустить.
В SpringBoot вроде как есть Jetty, но че-то я последние упоминания о нем как минимум 5 летной давности.

Подскажите а какой ваще сервер популярен в разработках web-приложений на java?

Я понимаю, что JAVA не для FrontEnd, но иногда просто необходимо какое-то небольшое GUI, а людей которые будут разрабатывать отдельно web интерфейс просто нет, а самому сильно погружаться в эту тему нет смысла. Вот и хотелось бы иметь одну рабочую связку Java + Сервер, вот только на чем остановиться.

Какой сервер посоветуете для изучения?

И еще один вопрос: как понять понадобиться мне будет когда-нибудь этот сервер, может мне и TomCat с головой хватит. Крупных web-приложений разрабатывать не собираюсь.

Какие преимущества у того же Payara (GlassFish) по сравнению с TomCat?

Comment: "вот только это не полноценный сервер" - на чем основано это утверждение?

Comment: я только изучаю эту тему и не смогу с вами тягаться в терминах, если я не прав, то просто напишите в чем именно. А информацию эту нашел в сети, кажется на хабре, там была статейка в которой говорилось, что Tomcat — это контейнер сервлетов, а не полноценный сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Особой разницы в программных серверах нет. Всё, что они делают - это принимают HTTP запросы и перенаправляют их для обработки в ваш Java код. После, Java код формирует строку, которую отдаёт обратно программному серверу и тот уже отдаёт эту строку в качестве ответа на клиент, который и делал изначальный запрос.

Таким образом, каких-то волшебных прорамм-серверов нет. Им просто негде делать магию. Используйте TomCat и можете даже не задумываться о том как оно работает и чем от других отличается.